# want to navigate between tab bars by using swipe gesters in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I want to use a swipe gesture to navigate between tab bar controllers while keep the default tab bars. I used this code but shows an error.

```
import UIKit

 class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        var leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))


        leftSwipe.direction = .Left


        view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

        func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
            if (sender.direction == .Left) {

                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! UIViewController
                self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)

            }

            if (sender.direction == .Right) {

            }
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: show error as " Thread 1: signal SIGABRT "

Comment: Remove handleSwipes function from inside the didReceiveMemoryWarning function.

Answer (score 2):

Your function `handleSwipes` must be a class level function, not an inner function of another function:

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    // remove the func from here
}

func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if (sender.direction == .Left) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! UIViewController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    if (sender.direction == .Right) {

    }
}
```

That is the obvious error I can see. You should always post your error message with your questions to improve the quality of answers.

Answer (score 1):

I could get your code working by adding the ID to the SecondViewController class as shown in the image below :

[image]

The only problem is, after getting this to work, you won't be able to see the Tab bar controller, since you have opened the SecondViewController which doesn't have the UI Tab bar controller.

Please let me know if my solution works and did you find any other way of swiping to second view and having the UI tab bar in place as well.

[EDIT]
Actually I dug down a bit more and found out it was easier than I expected. 
The fix to our problem of tabBar controller not showing up is as follows :

```
   func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        let selectedIndex: Int = self.tabBarController!.selectedIndex
        self.tabBarController!.selectedIndex = selectedIndex + 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this one :)

Comment: Added fix for the tab bar controller not showing up after swiping to SecondViewController. This is a more generic solution. Let me know if you need more help on this.

Comment: @Chathuranga :Please mark this question as answered and one up the solution, if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way for UITabBarViewController (Swift 3.0) will be next:

func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

```
    if sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left {

        self.selectedIndex += 1

    } else if sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right {

        self.selectedIndex -= 1
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want to go this route, you should at least check if the index is within bounds (>=0 and <amount of tabs)

Answer (score 1):

copy ad paste this

```
class SwipeGesture: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let left = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeLeft))
        left.direction = .left
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(left)

        let right = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeRight))
        right.direction = .right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(right)

    }

    @objc func swipeLeft() {
        let total = self.tabBarController!.viewControllers!.count - 1
        tabBarController!.selectedIndex = min(total, tabBarController!.selectedIndex + 1)

    }

    @objc func swipeRight() {
        tabBarController!.selectedIndex = max(0, tabBarController!.selectedIndex - 1)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use **UITabBarControllerDelegate** methods to accomplish this. There are new delegate methods on UITabBarControllerDelegate that lets you return **UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning** and **UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning**.

These are the delegate methods that you would use,

```
- (id <UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning>)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
                      interactionControllerForAnimationController: (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationController;

- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
            animationControllerForTransitionFromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC
                                              toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC;
```

The Swift code for the delegate methods look like this,

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, interactionControllerForAnimationController animationController: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning?

func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, animationControllerForTransitionFromViewController fromVC: UIViewController, toViewController toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?
```

Comment: Is This is a swift code ? , i'm new to swift , so could you please tell me how to modify above code to make it work , Thank you !!

Comment: No it is Objective C, I got it from api header. You could get swift code if you look into UITabViewControllerDelegate, I will add swift code also.

Comment: please update the swift code :) Thank you in advanced

Comment: @ChathurangaSilva did you ever manage to get this working for a UITabBarController?

Comment: @SoundShock not yet :(