# Swipe between tabs

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uitabbarcontroller

How can I get a side by side transition using a tabBarController. Just like a "normal" ScrollView paging.

Something like this: [image]

At the moment I'm using CrossDissolve:

```
class TransitioningObject: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

  func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let fromView: UIView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)!
    let toView: UIView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)!

    transitionContext.containerView()!.addSubview(fromView)
    transitionContext.containerView()!.addSubview(toView)

    UIView.transitionFromView(fromView, toView: toView, duration: transitionDuration(transitionContext), options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve) { finished in
        transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
    }
  }

  func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
    return 0.25
  }
}
```

As an extension of the side by side transition I would like to add a swipe gesture on the tab self.view. But that's a later problem, now I need to find out how to make the transition.

Comment: I used https://github.com/kitasuke/PagingMenuController where I also got the gif from in my question. Turned out to work as I wanted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [want to navigate between tab bars by using swipe gesters in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31783044/want-to-navigate-between-tab-bars-by-using-swipe-gesters-in-swift)